# failed to uninstall a pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

trying uninstall a pip

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pika==0.9.14 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo==2.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Collecting requests==2.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached requests-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask-restful==0.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyaml==15.5.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): graypy==0.2.11 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto3==1.2.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): raven==5.27.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask>=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): aniso8601>=0.82 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyYAML in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyaml==15.5.7->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3==1.2.3->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): botocore<1.4.0,>=1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3==1.2.3->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from boto3==1.2.3->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): contextlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from raven==5.27.1->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask>=0.8->flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask>=0.8->flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask>=0.8->flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from aniso8601>=0.82->flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from botocore<1.4.0,>=1.3.0->boto3==1.2.3->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask>=0.8->flask-restful==0.3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Installing collected packages: requests
  Found existing installation: requests 2.8.0
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 695, in uninstall
    for path in pip.wheel.uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 535, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 554, in uninstallation_paths
    r = csv.reader(FakeFile(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1477, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1469, in get_metadata
    return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1580, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.8.0.dist-info/RECORD'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

can't seem to find a workaround or how to convince a pip that this is not installed.

Comment: Try `--force-reinstall`? Or, run your pip with `-I, --ignore-installed`.

Comment: Have you tried running this inside a virtualenv?

Comment: If you used virtual_env's, installs wouldn't be a problem because it's an isolated environment. If you set one up, and run your code through one then you can install everything you please and it wont affect your base installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing the directory :

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.8.0.dist-info/
```

that way, it's not trying to uninstall anything

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix your problem - is uninstall Python, and install Python agan.

Or make automatic upgrade:

python -m pip install SomePackage

if will automatically fix you problem, and install newest version pipi

Comment: hi @Sergei , tried that and still getting `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.8.0.dist-info/RECORD'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`